# How do I show $eIe = I \cap eRe$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification, ideals

> Let $R$ be an associative ring with $1_R$ and $e \in R$ be an
> idempotent element such that $e^2 = e$. Show that
>
> (a) $eRe$ is a ring in itself with identity $e$
>
> (b) For any two sided ideal $I \subset R$, $I \cap eRe = eIe$

$(a)$ Do I just show all the properties or is there a faster way? For example what I mean is show

(i) Abelian in $+$, for any $x,y \in eRe$, x+y = er_1e + er_2e = e(r_1e +r_2e) =e(r_1 + r_2)e = e(r_2 + r_1)e = y + x. The third equality uses $R$ is a ring.

(ii) Assoc Multiplication. $(xy)z = (er_1e er_2 e)(er_3e) =\dots = x(yz)$

(iii) Distributive property $x(y + z) = \dots = xy + xz$ so forth and so forth.

(b) I only have to show set equality right?

So if $x \in I \cap eRe$, then $x = ere$ for some $r \in R$. But $exe = ere$ and $exe \in eIe$. Therefore $x = ere = exe \in eIe$ so $I \cap eRe \subset eIe.$

All I can deduce for the other equality is that for $y \in eIe$, we have $y = exe \in eIe$ and clearly $eIe \subset eRe$. Here is what I got stuck.

Comment: Can I clarify my answer in any way?

Comment: Well since you asked, I just want to know if there were more efficient ways to do (a) without checking each property one by one

Comment: No not really, but every property except unitality, is immediately inherited from the corresponding property in the original ring so this is quite fast. I don't see why you want a quicker way because this takes 30secs to write down.

Comment: Basically what you are using is that $eIe$ is a subring of $R$, but not necessarily with the same unit, and you can prove similar subring criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a) You show all the ring properties yes, but things like associativity or distributivity immediately follow from the corresponding properties in the ring $R$.

(b) In fact, the inclusion you are stuck at is trivial: If $y = exe \in eIe$ with $x \in I$, then clearly $y = exe \in eRe$ and since $I$ is an ideal also $y = exe \in I$, so $eIe \subseteq I \cap eRe.$

Comment: (a) Is this the only way? I find it an exercise on my hands to write this out. Or is it wrong to define $x \to exe$ and maybe show it is a homomorphism? (b) What is $E$?

Comment: Oh i think I see what you mean. Because $I$ is a two sided ideal, $eIe \subset I$ and hence the inclusion

Comment: Yes sorry E was a typo it should have been I.